# Something we found when using comma in condition ternary operator?

Tags: c++, ternary

Well, I had a question about comma in ternary operator.
Cut the crap, the code is below:

```
void test_comma_in_condition(void)
{
    int ia, ib, ic;

    ia = ib = ic = 0;
    bool condition=true;

    cout<<"Original:"<<endl;
    cout<<"ia: "<<ia<<endl;
    cout<<"ib: "<<ib<<endl;
    condition?(ia=1, ib=2):(ia=11, ib=12);
    cout<<"After:"<<endl;
    cout<<"ia: "<<ia<<endl;
    cout<<"ib: "<<ib<<endl;

    ia = ib = ic = 0;
    condition?ia=1, ib=2, ic=3:ib=22,ia=21, ic=23;
    cout<<"The operation must be bracketed, or you'll see..."<<endl;
    cout<<"ia: "<<ia<<endl;
    cout<<"ib: "<<ib<<endl;
    cout<<"ic: "<<ic<<endl;

    condition?ia=1, ib=2, ic=3:ia=21, ib=22, ic=23;
    cout<<"The operation must be bracketed, or you'll see..."<<endl;
    cout<<"ia: "<<ia<<endl;
    cout<<"ib: "<<ib<<endl;
    cout<<"ic: "<<ic<<endl; 

    return;
}
```

The output will be like:

```
Original:
ia: 0
ib: 0
After:
ia: 1
ib: 2
The operation must be bracketed, or you'll see...
ia: 21
ib: 2
ic: 23
The operation must be bracketed, or you'll see...
ia: 1
ib: 22
ic: 23
```

Is this legal?

Comment: You're saying `a ? b : c, d` should mean `a ? b : (c, d)` instead of `(a ? b : c), d`. Without getting into the question of which is correct, what is your reason for doubting the compiler?

Comment: Yes it is legal - but also unreadable.

Answer (score 8):

This is a matter of operator precedence. Your expression:

```
condition?ia=1, ib=2, ic=3:ib=22,ia=21, ic=23;
```

is understood by the compiler as:

```
(condition?(ia=1, ib=2, ic=3):(ib=22)),ia=21, ic=23;
```

At this point you should be able to see why you get the program output.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, but if this is a matter of precedence why does `,` appear to have higher precedence than `?:` in the "middle" of the conditional expression but lower precedence in tail of the conditional expression?

Comment: I +1'd your answer because it answered this good question - comma expressions are part of `expression` but not of `assignment-expression`.

Comment: You can't really invoke precedence here.  Formally, C++ operators aren't ordered by precedence, but by different productions in the grammar.  Most of the time, the effect is the same as if there were a precedence corresponding to the order the productions are presented in the standard, but there are at least two exceptions:  here (where the second term can be _any_ expression), and in some cases involving C style casts and prefix operators.

Comment: @JamesKanze If an almost-C++-but-not-quite language worked with precedence and used it to resolve ambiguities in the grammar, this isn't an example where the behaviour would differ, because the expression `a ? b, c : d` wouldn't be ambiguous in the first place.

Comment: @hvd If C++ was defined using precedence, either `a ? b : c, d` would group `a ? b : (c, d)` or `a ? b , c : d` would be illegal.

Comment: @JamesKanze In that fictional language, if `,` has lower precedence than `?:`, `a ? b , c : d` would still be valid because the grammar defines exactly one possible parse. Precedence is ignored, because precedence is used only when the grammar allows multiple parses.

Comment: @JamesKanze Wait, I think I see why we draw different conclusions... Your hypothetical language has binary `?` and `:` operators? If so, you're right. In my hypothetical language, `?:` is still a ternary operator.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the relevant grammar for a conditional expression is:

```
logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

for assignment expressions (which can also be a *conditional-expression* or a *throw-expression*):

```
logical-or-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

and for an expression with a comma operator (an *assignment-expression* can also be an *expression*):

```
expression , assignment-expression
```

This means that the construct `a ? b : c, d` cannot be parsed as equivalent to `a ? b : (c, d)` because `c, d` is not an *assignment-expression* but must be parsed as equivalent to `(a ? b : c), d`.

There is no undefined behaviour in `condition ? ia=1,ib=2,ic=3 : ia=21, ib=22, ic=23;` because evaluation of `condition` is sequenced before the evaluation of either the second or third operands of `?:` and in every sub-expression containing a comma operator the evaluation of the first operand of the comma operator is sequenced before the evaluation of the second operand.

Comment: Thanks a lot, maybe I need something about expression and assignment-expression.

Answer (score 3):

It's legal, but <strike>stupid</strike> not very useful to write code like that.

The code

```
condition?ia=1, ib=2, ic=3:ia=21, ib=22, ic=23;
```

is equivalent to

```
condition?(ia=1, ib=2, ic=3):ia=21;
ib=22;
ic=23;
```

just harder to read.

Comment: Another question? How does the comma parsed here? Or how the comma is used?

Comment: The comma operator can be used to separate expressions, like it does here. Unlike the semicolon, which *terminates* the expression, the comma allows you to have several expressions in a place that would otherwise only allow one. Not very useful in practice, and likely to cause confusion to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the comma operator has [the lowest precedence there is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Thanks to that, the `else` part of the conditional operator is just the first assignment, after that the comma operator kicks in and the other two statements will be executed just aswell.