# Why are multiple statements in ternary operator not executed

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

I am puzzled by the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  bool a = true;
  int nb = 1;
  int nb2 = 2;
  a ? nb++, nb2++ : nb--, nb2--;
  std::cout << " (nb,nb2) = (" << nb << "," << nb2 << ")";
}
```

Result:

```
(nb,nb2) = (2,2)
```

Why is `nb2` not equal to `3`?

Comment: a) don't use comma operator unless you strictly need it (because *it's evil*), b) don't use ternary to produce side effects - use ternary to get a conditional *value* only.

Comment: @NathanOliver: the interesting question is: why does this compile without any warnings ?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, I actually jumped the gun on this one. I retracted the close vote but it seems it doesn't remove the associated comment.

Comment: @Borgleader: You can just delete the comment if you like (but I think somebody else voted to close).

Comment: I don't think the last `,` is participating where you think it is. You seem to think this is `a ? (nb++, nb2++) : (nb--, nb2--);`. In reality, it is `(a ? (nb++, nb2++) : nb--), nb2--;`

Comment: @PaulR What would be the warning?  This does not do what you think it does?

Comment: The comma operator has the lowest precedence of any operator. The LHS of the comma expression is `a ? nb++, nb2++ : nb--`; the RHS is `nb2--`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I wasn't actually suggesting it *should* give a warning - it just looks so wrong that it was initially surprising (to me at least) that it even compiled.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't (and can't) have multiple statements within an expression. You have multiple *expressions* within an expression.

Comment: @KeithThompson Should I reopen and close this as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136156/whats-the-precedence-of-comma-operator-inside-conditional-operator-in-c to get rid of the dupe link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of operators priority. Your expression evaluates as

```
((a) ? (nb++, nb2++) : nb--), nb2--;
```

Operator `,` (`comma`) is the last thing to process. And this example would not compile at all but

> The expression in the middle of the conditional operator (between ? and :) is parsed as if parenthesized.

See [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence#cite_note-2) for details.

Answer (score 4):

use paranthesis:

```
a ? (nb++, nb2++) : (nb--, nb2--);
```

reason: lexical analysis

Answer (score 4):

It's expected behaviour.

Your expression is understood by the compiler as:

```
((a) ? (nb++, nb2++) : nb--), nb2--;
```

For more details see:

- [Something we found when using comma in condition ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189522/something-we-found-when-using-comma-in-condition-ternary-operator)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator